# SSIS Oracle source conatins no output columns

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am trying to develop an SSIS package that truncates a table in Oracle db. Unfortunately i am getting an error [image]

1. When i am trying to do select from the truncated table, it works fine - connection manager is setup correctly. I've recreated connection manager just in case but that did help.
2. Truncated table is in the same schema as the user on which ETL is runned.
3. Despite an error message, task does it's job. Table get's truncated but error message still appears.

Any ideas what could be the reason?
Regards,
Lukas
2.

Comment: Shouldn't you be showing us what SSIS component you used, what is the code/configuration of it?

Answer (score 0):

Component that i used is Oracle Source task inside of DFT.Oracle source is using a query "TRUNCATE TABLE schema_Name.TableName":

[image]

[image]
When i use "SELECT * FROM schema_Name.TableName" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution.
Instead of using "SQL command" inside of Oracle Source task i used "Execute SQL Task" with the same query. I connected to Oracle db using OLE DB.